# Deleting drawn polygons in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a project and I ended up using Fusion Tables. However, I want to deal with Event Listeners. For this reason, I'm using a technology called JSONP.

In the example I showed below (fiddle), It has both fusion table (Red Fill) and a JSONP (No Fill with Black stroke) working together, just to picture what I'm trying to achieve.

Each time the user presses the button "GO" I want to draw all the polygons returned by the JSONP request, with its attributes

[This first example](http://jsfiddle.net/wLuhktu4/35/) re-draws the polygons but only one.

[The second Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wLuhktu4/34/)draws all the polygons but doesn't delete the old ones. (I tried to use `Regions.setMap(null);` e `delete Regions;` and didn't work)

So, what I want is a suggestion how I could only draw in the map the polygons the user queried maintaining its attributes.

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function initMap() { //http://devfestmtm.appspot.com/#1

      var mapProp = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: {
          lat: -18.92990560776172,
          lng: -43.4406814550781
        },
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapProp);

      //Instantiate the InfoWindow
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        maxWidth: 350,
        //pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,5)
      });

      //************* Loading Fusion Table

      var tableId = '1WMlA-1ik05epxVKu0l5Pgyi5WtmCg1W3-akwE4Ps';
      var locationColumn = 'geometry';
      var Regioes_AOI_FusionTable = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: locationColumn,
          from: tableId
        },
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        map: map,
      });


      google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('ButtonFilter'), 'click', function() {
        UpdateFusionTable(Regioes_AOI_FusionTable, tableId, locationColumn);
      });

    } // End Map


  function UpdateFusionTable(Regioes_AOI_FusionTable, tableId, locationColumn) {
    var queryGenerated = document.getElementById('Regions').value;

    Regioes_AOI_FusionTable.setOptions({
      query: {
        select: locationColumn,
        from: tableId,
        where: queryGenerated
      }
    });

    // Initialize JSONP request
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?'];
    url.push('sql=');
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tableId + " WHERE " + queryGenerated;
    var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);
    url.push(encodedQuery);
    url.push('&callback=drawMap'); //Calls the drawMap function
    url.push('&key=AIzaSyCoC9A3WgFneccRufbysInygnWrhCie-T0');
    script.src = url.join('');
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.appendChild(script);

  }

  function drawMap(data) {

    var rows = data['rows'];
    for (var i in rows) {
      var newCoordinates = [];

      newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates(rows[i][1]['geometry']);

      Regions = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: newCoordinates,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillOpacity: 0,


        //retrieve all the Fusion Table information for each row
        row: (function(index) {
          var row = {};
          for (var j = 0; j < data['rows'][index].length; ++j) {
            row[data.columns[j]] = data['rows'][index][j];
          }
          return row;
        })(i)
      });

      //Working Mouseover event
      google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'mouseover', function() {
        this.setOptions({
          strokeWeight: 3
        });
      });
      //Working Mouseout event
      google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'mouseout', function() {
        this.setOptions({
          strokeWeight: 1
        });
      });


      // Working click event
      google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'click', function(event) {
        var Content = this.row['Sigla_Muni'];
        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow.setContent(Content);
        infowindow.open(map);

      });

      Regions.setMap(map);
    }

  }

  //access the lat and long for each node and return a array containing those values, extracted from fusion table.
  function constructNewCoordinates(polygon) {
    var newCoordinates = [];
    var coordinates = polygon['coordinates'][0];
    for (var i in coordinates) {
      newCoordinates.push(
        // write the lat and long respectively
        new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][0]));
    }
    return newCoordinates;
  }
</script>
<div>
  <select id="Regions">
    <br>
    <option value="Sigla_Muni = 'CMD'">CMD</option>
    <option value="Sigla_Muni = 'AM'">AM</option>
    <option value="Sigla_Muni = 'DJ'">DJ</option>
  </select>


  <button type="button" id="ButtonFilter">Go!</button>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBFYwb6-B6u2cs5oknTRwtfBng2kgdDMgk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: "In the example I showed above" - where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to keep references to the polygons in an array (ie.e gmarkers), then set the map property of *all* the polygons to null (to hide them) before creating any new ones.

```
for (var i in rows) {
    var newCoordinates = [];
    newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates(rows[i][1]['geometry']);
    var Regions = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: newCoordinates,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        //retrieve all the Fusion Table information for each row
        row: (function(index){
                    var row={};
                        for(var j=0;j<data['rows'][index].length;++j){
                        row[data.columns[j]]=data['rows'][index][j];
                    }
                    return row;
                })(i)
    });
    //Working Mouseover event
    google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'mouseover', function() {
        this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 3});
    });
    //Working Mouseout event
    google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'mouseout', function() {
        this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 1});
    });
    // Working click event
    google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'click', function (event) {
        var Content = this.row['Sigla_Muni'];
        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow.setContent(Content);
        infowindow.open(map);
    });

    Regions.setMap(map);
    gpolygons.push(Regions);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wLuhktu4/36/)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script>
  function initMap() { //http://devfestmtm.appspot.com/#1

      var mapProp = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: {
          lat: -18.92990560776172,
          lng: -43.4406814550781
        },
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapProp);

      //Instantiate the InfoWindow
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        maxWidth: 350,
        //pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0,5)
      });

      //************* Loading Fusion Table

      var tableId = '1WMlA-1ik05epxVKu0l5Pgyi5WtmCg1W3-akwE4Ps';
      var locationColumn = 'geometry';
      var Regioes_AOI_FusionTable = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: locationColumn,
          from: tableId
        },
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        map: map,
      });


      google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('ButtonFilter'), 'click', function() {
        UpdateFusionTable(Regioes_AOI_FusionTable, tableId, locationColumn);
      });

    } // End Map


  function UpdateFusionTable(Regioes_AOI_FusionTable, tableId, locationColumn) {
    var queryGenerated = document.getElementById('Regions').value;

    Regioes_AOI_FusionTable.setOptions({
      query: {
        select: locationColumn,
        from: tableId,
        where: queryGenerated
      }
    });

    // Initialize JSONP request
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?'];
    url.push('sql=');
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tableId + " WHERE " + queryGenerated;
    var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);
    url.push(encodedQuery);
    url.push('&callback=drawMap'); //Calls the drawMap function
    url.push('&key=AIzaSyCoC9A3WgFneccRufbysInygnWrhCie-T0');
    script.src = url.join('');
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.appendChild(script);

  }

  var gpolygons = [];

  function drawMap(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < gpolygons.length; i++) {
      gpolygons[i].setMap(null);
    }
    var rows = data['rows'];
    for (var i in rows) {
      var newCoordinates = [];
      newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates(rows[i][1]['geometry']);
      var Regions = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: newCoordinates,
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillOpacity: 0,
        //retrieve all the Fusion Table information for each row
        row: (function(index) {
          var row = {};
          for (var j = 0; j < data['rows'][index].length; ++j) {
            row[data.columns[j]] = data['rows'][index][j];
          }
          return row;
        })(i)
      });

      //Working Mouseover event
      google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'mouseover', function() {
        this.setOptions({
          strokeWeight: 3
        });
      });
      //Working Mouseout event
      google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'mouseout', function() {
        this.setOptions({
          strokeWeight: 1
        });
      });


      // Working click event
      google.maps.event.addListener(Regions, 'click', function(event) {
        var Content = this.row['Sigla_Muni'];
        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow.setContent(Content);
        infowindow.open(map);

      });

      Regions.setMap(map);
      gpolygons.push(Regions);
    }

  }

  //access the lat and long for each node and return a array containing those values, extracted from fusion table.
  function constructNewCoordinates(polygon) {
    var newCoordinates = [];
    var coordinates = polygon['coordinates'][0];
    for (var i in coordinates) {
      newCoordinates.push(
        // write the lat and long respectively
        new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][0]));
    }
    return newCoordinates;
  }
</script>
<div>
  <select id="Regions">
    <br>
    <option value="Sigla_Muni = 'CMD'">CMD</option>
    <option value="Sigla_Muni = 'AM'">AM</option>
    <option value="Sigla_Muni = 'DJ'">DJ</option>
  </select>


  <button type="button" id="ButtonFilter">Go!</button>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBFYwb6-B6u2cs5oknTRwtfBng2kgdDMgk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```